# Smart Contract Re-deployment on Ropsten Testnet

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment

I have deployed the same Smart Contract twice on the Ropsten Testnet using Truffle (i.e. truffle migrate --compile-all --reset --network ropsten). The second deployment generated a new contract address, different than the initial one. If I use the web3 command smartContractName.address, the second address is returned.

I was wondering what happen to the first Smart Contract deployed at the initial address? Is it still accessible somehow? What would happen if I did the same on Mainnet (besides costing me real ETHs, of course)? Is the behaviour identical?

Comment: That deployed contract will be there as well. There is not overriding or deleting the previous one.

Comment: Thank you @blockByblock This is what I had assumed. However, upon calling smartContractName.address, the new address is returned? Is the blockchain designed to return only the latest address in such cases?